# Trying to get data from React web app and into Electron app to display a badge count

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm trying to get data out of my web app and use it inside the electron app to display a badge count of unread messages, similar to slack.  I've got the `app.dock.setBadge({someNumber})` in `Main.js`, and I've got a callback inside my `src/component`.

What is the best way to connect the website and the electron app?  I'm really struggling with the IPC concept on taking it to the next level.  I understand how it works going between the renderer and main, but I'm trying to connect the data being provided inside my `React` component to the `Electron` component and display an accurate `badgeCount` of unread messages.

Comment: Are you asking why the badge isn't working, or for the best way to keep a desktop app with a website in sync

Comment: The latter, how to best keep the desktop app in sync with the website. Thank you for helping me clarify!

Comment: What you mean by " I've got a callback inside my src/component"? Care to show some more code to clarify your problem?

Comment: I probably would just use `require('electron').remote.app.dock.setBadge()` right inside React component.

Comment: That was a great help!  Thank you.  I don't know why I didn't think of doing this in the first place!